# Is checking sentences here acceptable?

Tags: discussion, questions

Sometimes I'm not sure in specific sentence, can I write it here to get opinion about it?

Not always I can explain what is the doubt that I have, it's more about the wording (I would like that it will sound as much as native).
For example in the following sentence:

"When drinking sweetened drink (such as cola) is it coming to the kidneys as water molecules?"

Answer (score 8):

**No** . . . **Yes** . . . Well, it just can't be answered in one word. Dang it!

Proofreading questions are [off-topic on ELL; unless you "provide a source of concern"](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258/should-proofreading-questions-be-closed-as-offtopic).
For example, this:

> ### Is my sentence grammatical?
>
> I just wanted to know if my sentence is grammatical. Here it is:
>
> > When drinking sweetened drink (such as cola) is it coming to the kidneys as water molecules?

Would raise the alarms as a proofreading request. It'll be closed as such. However, you can easily "limit it to what you wanna, say, check". Like this:

> ### "is it coming" vs. "does it come"
>
> I recently wanted to comment on [this question](http://somequestion) on [this SE site](http://someSEsite). However, I ran into a problem when deciding on which structure to use:
>
> > When drinking sweetened drink (such as cola) (**is it coming/does it come**) to the kidneys as water molecules?
>
> *(Optional)* I know that the progressive aspect is used for an action that is . . . while simple present tense is used for . . .

I wouldn't imagine this question's closure (see [this](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/stop-throwing-proofreading-close-reason-at-questions-that-are-clearly-limited)). As an alternative, you could check [these sites](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/alternative-websites-for-proofreading) out.