# Is there anything to be corrected?

Tags: support

I have a question about my English Language Learners Stack Exchange post: [Is there anything to be corrected?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183280/is-there-anything-to-be-corrected)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't actually ask anything, so I assume you want to know why it was put on hold and how it can be reopened. On a desktop, there is a banner that gives the reason. On the app, that info is hidden. You have to tap the icon to reveal the reason. In any case, the reason should something like

> **put on hold** as off-topic by Em.♦ 23 hours ago
> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - "Questions asking for someone to **find and correct errors** or **improve the phrasing** are considered requests for proofreading and are off-topic. Please edit your question to focus on **something in particular** that you are unsure about; if that's not possible, see [websites for proofreading](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/alternative-websites-for-proofreading) instead." – Em.
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/183280/edit).

I usually leave a comment with links, though I didn't this time for whatever reason. I might write something like

> You can ask about the usage of a word or phrase, but please [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/183280/edit) your post and specify a concern. Asking us to check your work is considered proofreading and off-topic here. Please see the [help center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for on-topic questions. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

If you edit your post to fit our guidelines, then your question will enter a queue to be considered for reopening. If your question receives enough reopen votes, or if a moderator casts a reopen vote, then your question will be reopened.

I assume you understand that this is [ELL Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/), where "[users discuss the workings and policies](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)" of the parent site, [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). We have a number of posts on ELL Meta discussing proofreading, but here is another recent one to give an additional example of what we expect from "proofreading" questions: [Rules about proofreading essays (IELTS etc.)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4808/rules-about-proofreading-essays-ielts-etc).