# Is there an online forum where native speakers correct your English sentences for you?

Tags: discussion

I'm not a native English speaker. but I want a forum which some native ones help others with checking their sentences. In this site, we are not allowed to do such things. I appreciate any help from anyone. god, bless you all :)

Comment: The [Alternative sites for Proofreading](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/alternative-websites-for-proofreading) thread may have some help. Unfortunately new sign-ups for lang-8.com are suspended - you will be redirected to HiNative, which is only available as an app (I think).